# Java: Issue with setSoTimeout and multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm programming a server which should keep alive the connection with a client as long as it sends commands through the socket.
Every time a new connection is accepted `soTimeout` is set to `60000` and the socket is passed to a Runnable which is submitted to a thread pool.

This is the main thread accepting new connections:

```
ExecutorService tpl = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
while (!isCancelled) {
    try {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        Socket socket = ss.accept();
        socket.setSoTimeout(60000);
        tpl.submit(new Player(socket));
    } catch(SocketException ignored) {
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
          ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is the loop in Player's run() method:

```
try(Socket socket = this.socket;
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter( socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"))) {

for(String msg = in.readLine(); msg != null; msg = in.readLine()){
        String[] cmd = msg.split(":");
        switch (cmd[0]) {
            case: "MOVE":
                //DO SOMETHING
                break;
            //...
        }
}
} catch(SocketTimeoutException e){
      game.removePlayer(this);
      game.broadcast("LOGOUT:" + username)
} catch(IOException e){
      e.printStackTrace()
}
```

The problem is despite the client doesn't write on the socket for 60 seconds, SocketTimeoutException is not always catched.
I couldn't find a pattern but I've noticed that the fewer are the clients connected the smaller is the chance the exception isn't thrown

Comment: NB Never ignore a `SocketException`.

Comment: I did it because it's usually raised when I close `ServerSocket ss` on purpose to shut down the server. If you say it could be a problem I'll handle it differently

Comment: Do you hava any ideas about how to solve my problem?